# Getting Dojo 1.9 to work with key events

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to wire up a Javascript event handler with Dojo 1.9 so that any time a key is pressed, the value will be checked to see if it's valid for the field it's being placed in.

However, I can't get the event to fire when I press a key.   Probably a typo or something stupid, but I just can't see it.

Here's a sample input tag and the JS code I'm using to wire up the inputs - can anybody point me to the problem:

```
<input id="field2" name="field2"
       data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
       data-dojo-props="constraints:{
       required: true,
       maxLength: 3},
        pattern:'[0-9]{1,2}',
        invalidMessage:'Please enter a number in this field.',
        rangeMessage:'Please enter a number between  and 99.',
        missingMessage:'This value is required.' "
        />



<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojox/validate",
        "dojox/validate/web",
        "dojox/validate/check",
        "dojox/validate/us",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
            function ( query, parser, dom, on, validate ) {

                var inputs = query("input");
                for (i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
                    var node = inputs[i];
                    on(node, "keydown", function(e) {
                        alert("I got called!");
                    });
                };

            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating a dojo ValidationTextBox, what dojo normally does is create a few wrappers around the input that handle events like keypress, keydown, etc. These wrappers also stop propagation so that you'll probably have to listen to the event emitted by the widgets themselves instead.

Try this instead:

```
var inputs = query(".dijitTextBox"); //Searching for all textboxes
for (i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  var node = inputs[i];
  var nodeWidget = registry.byNode(node);
  on(nodeWidget, "keydown", function(e) {
    alert("I got called!");
  });
};
```

Note that with the code above, you'll probably have to require "dijit/registry" too.